# Cannot format memory stick to fat32

Tags: format, fat32

I am trying to format my usb stick on `/dev/sdc`, partition `sdc1`:

```
sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdc1
```

I get the following for a few seconds, no error:

```
mkfs.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)
```

However, `sudo fdisk -l` lists `/dev/sdc1` as 'Linux':

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048   122879999    61438976   83  Linux
```

and I still can't mount it on a FAT32-only system.

I have tried to [zero the stick first](https://askubuntu.com/a/168937/4246), [sfdisk](https://askubuntu.com/a/57893/4246), removing `-F 32`, nothing works.

How do I format my USB stick?

---

Edit: I tried to format from nautilus. It doesn't work either, but at least I get an error message:

"Error synchronizing after initial wipe: Timed out waiting for object (udisks-error-quark, 0)"

Comment: Is the stick writeable (some have a little switch on them to write-lock)?

Comment: Good point! I see no physical switch, but when I mount the stick, it is root:root with permissions 0755...

Comment: @ubfan1: If I mount the disk with `sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/usbdrive/ -o umask=000`, I can create a file at the mount point.

Answer (score 2):

[Apparently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377253/unable-to-format-usb-drive-with-disks-udisks-error-quark-0), this is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/util-linux/+bug/1059872), but `gparted` manages to format.

Strange that I get an error message when trying to format from nautilus, but not from the command line.